# Correlated residuals - white noise analysis

Tags: autocorrelation, residuals, fourier-transform, white-noise

I want to check and analyze the goodness of my compressed sensing reconstruction algorithm (fit) using the autocorrelation of the residuals. Given my problem, I guess there are two ways to do this:

1. Analyze the residuals in Fourier space, where noise is independent.
2. Analyze the residuals in image space where each sample is correlated to a group of neighbours inside an ugly Gaussian, also known as PSF.

Basically I want to make a quantitative statement like: "With a x% confidence interval it is possible to say that the residuals are noise-like).

Let's say that I do the white noise analysis in Fourier space where measurements are uncorrelated and it's easier. Would be possible to state the same in the image space given the first?

Cheers